# I want to pay gas fee from contract, Is it possible?

Tags: contract-development, smart-contract-wallets

// here is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library SafeMath {
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
        uint256 c = a - b;
        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, "SafeMath: division by zero");
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }
}

contract ThetaVibes {
    using SafeMath for uint256; // Import SafeMath library
     mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
 struct Video {
        uint256 price;
        uint256 price48Hours;
        uint256 priceLifetime;
        mapping(address => bool) lifetimeAccess;
    }
    
      struct Channel {
        address payable owner;
        mapping(string => Video) videos;
        uint256 channelBalance;
        uint256 subscriptionPrice;
        mapping(address => bool) subscribers;
    }

        struct Subscription {
        bool isActive;
    }

    address payable contractOwnerAddress;

    constructor() {
        contractOwnerAddress = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == contractOwnerAddress, "Only the contract owner can call this function.");
        _;
    }

    mapping(string => Channel) public channels;

    mapping(string => mapping(address => Subscription)) public subscriptions;


    event SubscriptionPurchased(string indexed channelId, address indexed subscriber);
    event VideoPurchased(string indexed channelId, string indexed videoId, address indexed purchaser, bool isLifetime);
    event ChannelOwnerWithdrawn(string indexed channelId, address indexed owner, uint256 amount);
    event ContractOwnerWithdrawn(address indexed owner, uint256 amount);
    event DepositMade(address indexed depositor, uint256 amount);
    event SubscriptionRemoved(string indexed channelId, address indexed subscriber);

  
    function createChannel(string memory channelId, uint256 subscriptionPriceTFuel) public {
        require(channels[channelId].owner == address(0), "Channel already exists");
        Channel storage newChannel = channels[channelId];
        newChannel.owner = payable(msg.sender);
        newChannel.subscriptionPrice = subscriptionPriceTFuel;
    }

function deposit() public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0, "Amount must be greater than zero");

    // Deduct gas fees from the deposited amount
    uint256 gasCost = gasleft() * tx.gasprice;
    uint256 depositedAmount = msg.value.sub(gasCost);

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(depositedAmount);

    emit DepositMade(msg.sender, depositedAmount);
}

function purchaseSubscriptionWithBalance(string memory channelId, address subscriber) public {
    Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
    require(channel.owner != address(0), "Channel does not exist");
    require(!channel.subscribers[subscriber], "Already subscribed to the channel");

    uint256 gasCost = gasleft() * tx.gasprice;
    uint256 totalCost = channel.subscriptionPrice.add(gasCost); // Calculate total cost

    require(balances[subscriber] >= totalCost, "Insufficient balance to cover subscription and gas fees");

    channel.subscribers[subscriber] = true;
    emit SubscriptionPurchased(channelId, subscriber);

    uint256 contractOwnerShare = (channel.subscriptionPrice * 20) / 100;
    uint256 channelOwnerShare = channel.subscriptionPrice - contractOwnerShare;

    channel.channelBalance += channelOwnerShare;
    balances[subscriber] = balances[subscriber].sub(channel.subscriptionPrice); // Deduct subscription price from user's balance

    // Call a separate function for gas-heavy operations
    processGas(subscriber, gasCost);
}

function processGas(address subscriber, uint256 gasCost) internal {
    balances[subscriber] = balances[subscriber].sub(gasCost); // Deduct gas cost from user's balance
    // Additional gas-heavy operations can be performed here
}
  


      function renewSubscriptionWithBalance(string memory channelId, address subscriber) public onlyOwner {
        Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
        require(channel.owner != address(0), "Channel does not exist");
        require(channel.subscribers[subscriber], "Subscriber is not subscribed to the channel");
        require(balances[subscriber] >= channel.subscriptionPrice, "Insufficient balance");

        channel.channelBalance += channel.subscriptionPrice; // Add subscription price to channel balance
        balances[subscriber] -= channel.subscriptionPrice; // Deduct subscription price from user's balance
      }


    function removeSubscription(string memory channelId, address subscriber) public onlyOwner {
        Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
        require(channel.owner != address(0), "Channel does not exist");
        require(channel.subscribers[subscriber], "Subscriber is not subscribed to the channel");

        channel.subscribers[subscriber] = false; // Set subscriber status to false to remove subscription

        emit SubscriptionRemoved(channelId, subscriber);
    }
 

function updateSubscriptionPrice(string memory channelId, uint256 newPrice) public {
    Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
    require(channel.owner == msg.sender, "Only the channel owner can update the subscription price");

    channel.subscriptionPrice = newPrice;
}

modifier onlyChannelOwner(string memory channelId) {
    require(channels[channelId].owner == msg.sender, "Only the channel owner can call this function.");
    _;
}

function createVideo(string memory channelId, string memory videoId, uint256 price48Hours, uint256 priceLifetime) public onlyChannelOwner(channelId) {
    Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
    require(channel.videos[videoId].price48Hours == 0, "Video already exists");

    Video storage newVideo = channel.videos[videoId];
    newVideo.price48Hours = price48Hours * 1e18;
    newVideo.priceLifetime = priceLifetime * 1e18;
}
    
function purchaseVideoWithBalance(string memory channelId, string memory videoId, bool lifetimeAccess) public {
    Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
    require(channel.owner != address(0), "Channel does not exist");
    require(channel.videos[videoId].price48Hours > 0, "Video does not exist");
    require(!channel.subscribers[msg.sender], "Subscribers cannot purchase videos from this channel");
    require(!channel.videos[videoId].lifetimeAccess[msg.sender], "Already purchased lifetime access to the video");

    uint256 videoPrice = (lifetimeAccess ? channel.videos[videoId].priceLifetime : channel.videos[videoId].price48Hours) / 1e18;

    require(balances[msg.sender] >= videoPrice, "Insufficient balance");

    if (lifetimeAccess) {
        channel.videos[videoId].lifetimeAccess[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    uint256 contractOwnerShare = (videoPrice * 20) / 100;
    uint256 channelOwnerShare = videoPrice - contractOwnerShare;

    channel.channelBalance += channelOwnerShare;
    balances[msg.sender] -= videoPrice;
    contractOwnerAddress.transfer(contractOwnerShare); // Transfer 20% to the contract owner
    emit VideoPurchased(channelId, videoId, msg.sender, lifetimeAccess);
}


    function channelOwnerWithdraw(string memory channelId) public {
        Channel storage channel = channels[channelId];
        require(channel.owner == msg.sender, "Only the channel owner can call this function");

        uint256 amount = channel.channelBalance;
        require(amount > 0, "No balance available for withdrawal");

        channel.channelBalance = 0;
        channel.owner.transfer(amount);
        emit ChannelOwnerWithdrawn(channelId, msg.sender, amount);
    }
    function isSubscriber(string memory channelId, address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return channels[channelId].subscribers[account];
    }


}
```

Comment: Please state clearly what you need instead of sharing a random contract with poor editing.

Comment: Thank You guiding, this my first time to asking question on this platform

Answer (score 1):

In general, in the Ethereum network, the price is paid by the one who initiated the transaction. The way around it (at the moment) are `Meta-transactions` + `Gas Relayers`

`Meta-transactions` allow users to sign messages (not transactions), which are then sent to a `Gas Relay`. After verifying these messages, the relay processes them as transactions **on-chain** and **pays for the gas fees**. The contract can then reimburse the relay or provide other compensations. This means from the user's perspective, they don't need to spend ETH, even though a transaction occurs on-chain. (Exactly what you are trying to do).

Comment: I have created function for consumer to deposited balance into contract, 
My goal is to deduct gas fee for purchasing subscription from his/her deposited balance as same as subscription is deducting from his/her balance, Can you explain is it possible ?

Comment: @IlyasKhan you are confusing gas fees I guess. Gas fees is something paid for the transaction to execute. Please explain your question properly.

Comment: @ZartajAfser I am working on smart contract in which is almost same as virtual wallet user deposit into my contract and i am storing their balance into contract. I want to achieve when they transaction their gas cost would also be deduct from virtual wallet, Is it possible ?

Comment: No, the gas cost is always deducted from the wallet that initiates a transaction. You can use meta transactions to make it gas less for the users and later deduct the price from their virtual wallet.